# ClosedXML report - format of input list

Tags: closedxml.report

The format for sending data to a closedXML template is a bit confusing to me.

In the [Flat tables docs](https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Flat-tables) there's a sample for a template with header info and data from a list for the report, but I don't see where the list is connected to the template.

I have a similar scenario - header info for the top, data in a list for the report.

I've tried defining an object with all the data in it:

```
public class AllocationExportData
{
    public List<AllocationExportItem> AllocationList { get; set; }
    public string Host_custname { get; set; }
    public string Host_custaddr { get; set; }

}
```

and setting up the template using those variables

[image]

But only the top two values are being found

[image]

I figure I'm naming something wrong, or setting up the object wrong.

Anyone?

Comment: have you fixed it i have encounter this error

Answer (score 0):

About `Host_city`, `Host_state` etc... you need to add equivalently named properties in your `AllocationExportData` class.

About the issues in the table "Credit Recipient Information":

The link between a table in the Excel template and a collection in code is indeed not explicitly described in the [ClosedXML.Report Quick Start](https://closedxml.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Quick-start). Fortunalty the [Flat Tables page](https://closedxml.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Flat-tables) of the official documentation gives the necessary explanations.

Basically:
You need to create a named range in your Excel sheet.
See [naming cells and ranges in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

The name of that range must be the name of the property representing the collection you wish to display on this table. Its type must implement `IEnumerable` (again see the [Flat Tables page](https://closedxml.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Flat-tables)).

In your case, you should name the range:
AllocationList

Now you have to define what is the range you want to name.
Since you want each element of your `AllocationList` to be stacked vertically (i.e. each one on a specific line, not displayed on the same line, each one at the right of the preceding one), you want to create what the documentation call a "vertical table".

The [Flat Tables page](https://closedxml.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/en/Flat-tables) states:

> Each range specifying a vertical table must have at least two columns
> and two rows. The leftmost column and bottommost row serve to hold
> configuration information and are treated specially. After the report
> is built the service column is cleared, and the service row is deleted
> if it is empty.

In your case, the range should include all the cells with the error "Unknown identifier [...]", plus a second empty row below.